# Run a Jupyter Notebook from another notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I’m trying to run a notebook from another notebook, the name of the notebook that i want to run is prepracion.ipynb from folder Procesamiento.

When I try this code:

```
%run Procesamiento\\Preparacion.ipynb
```

This is the result:

```
Exception: File `'Procesamiento.ipynb.py'` not found.
```

I don’t know what I’m doing wrong. Any help?

The Notebook I’m currently running is:

```
C:\Users\Iván\OneDrive - Eidos Analytics\Naviera\Proyectos\Predecir Vel\Modelo
```

and the folder the notebook I want run:

```
C:\Users\Iván\OneDrive - Eidos Analytics\Naviera\Proyectos\Predecir Vel\Modelo\Procesamiento
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check a path of your file and try to place it in the main location where jupyter notebook installed or try as below. I hope it will work.

/folder/filename.ipynb